# Binding ViewModel with a list of ViewModels including HttpPostedFileBase to controller action

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, mvvm

Okay, so i'm gonna try my  best to explain the problem i'm facing at the moment.

I want to have a create view, which is strongly typed to a ViewModel. The ViewModel has some properties, where one of them is a list, containing ViewModels of another kind. That ViewModel contains some more properties, plus a value of type HttpPostedFileBase.

The createView should contain a file input for each of the viewModels, in the List. All other properties are going to be hidden from the user. The only thing that needs user interaction is the HttpPostedFileBase.

The thing is, firstly, i cannot get EditorFor to create a file input, and believe me lord iv'e tried. Secondly, i need to do it for every entry in the list of the strongly typed viewModel (TestViewModel below), so it can bind the values back to the controller on post.

The reason im creating this, as a test project, is that i need to see what the HTML would look like, in order for the asp.net binder to be able to bind it to the controller post action.

Please, if you dont understand the problem above, feel free to ask questions. I will do my best to answer. Thanks !

Simplified example classes.

```
public class TestViewModel
{
    public string SomeString { get; set; }
    public int SomeInt { get; set; }
    public List<ImageViewModel> ImageViewModels { get; set; }
}

public class ImageViewModel
{
    [DataType(DataType.Upload)]
    public HttpPostedFileBase Value { get; set; }
}
```

Create View (simplified, i know. It's a test project)

```
@model WebApplication1.Models.TestViewModel

@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Create";
}

<h2>Create</h2>


@using (Html.BeginForm("Create", "Home", FormMethod.Post, new { enctype = "multipart/form-data" }))
{
    @Html.AntiForgeryToken()

    <div class="form-horizontal">
        <h4>TestViewModel</h4>
        <hr />
        @Html.ValidationSummary(true, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })

        <div>
            <table>
                <tr>
                    <th>Image</th>
                </tr>
                @for (int i = 0; i < Model.ImageViewModels.Count; i++)
                {
                    <td>@Html.EditorFor(m => m.ImageViewModels[i].Value)</td>
                }
            </table>
        </div>

        <div class="form-group">
            <div class="col-md-offset-2 col-md-10">
                <input type="submit" value="Create" class="btn btn-default" />
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
}

<div>
    @Html.ActionLink("Back to List", "Index")
</div>

@section Scripts {
    @Scripts.Render("~/bundles/jqueryval")
}
```

Comment: Unless you have created a custom `EditorTemplate`, you will need to use `@Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.ImageViewModels[i].Value, new { type = "file" })`

Comment: @StephenMuecke I just tried it very briefly, with what seems to be a positive outcome. Im gonna look deeper into it later today. Could you please add your comment as an answer, so i can give you credit?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `EditorFor()` method will generate an input for each property of `HttpPostedFileBase`, not an `<input type="file" .../>`. The `EditorFor()` method uses the [TemplateHelpers](https://aspnetwebstack.codeplex.com/SourceControl/latest#src/System.Web.Mvc/Html/TemplateHelpers.cs) to determine which template to use to generate the html, and unfortunately there is not one corresponding to `[DataType(DataType.Upload)]`

You can use the following to create the input

```
@Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.ImageViewModels[i].Value, new { type = "file" })
```

or alternatively create an `EditorTemplate` for typeof `HttpPostedFileBase` so that you can use the `EditorFor()` method

In `/Views/Shared/EditorTemplates/HttpPostedFileBase.cshtml`

```
@model HttpPostedFileBase
@Html.TextBoxFor(m => m, new { type = "file" })
```

Comment: Short, precise but thorough answer. Thanks!